# Unable to locate element in search dialog box

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have opened a search dialog box with the help of robot class but now I am trying to enter the text in that search dialog box but it is not entering the text with help of robot keypress.

The source code is as below

On Click of Add Row button as below a search dialog window opened up

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sale_dtl_ig_toolbar\"]/div[1]/div[6]/button")).click();
```

// Code to open search dialog box

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);

    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    Thread.sleep(5000); // sometimes there may be a delay for the dialog box to get appeared
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    Dimension i = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    System.out.println("Dimension x and y  :"+i.getHeight()+","+i.getWidth());

    int x = (i.getWidth()/4 )+ 20;
    int y = (i.getHeight()/10)+ 50;

    robot.mouseMove(x,y);

    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    ....................... upto this code search dialog window appears with one search dropdown

    //driver.findElement(By.id("SEARCH")).sendKeys("");
  //*[@id="SEARCH"] ............ here i had tried to locate the element but it is thowing exception unable to locate element
```

Then i used below code to type in the search field but it also doesn;t work

```
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_U);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
```

Comment: Are you not able to send the text through Selenium `sendKeys()` command? Also, can you give the error if any and the page HTML structure that would be helpful

Comment: I don't understand why you are using Java Robot instead of using Selenium's browser interaction methods like Actions. https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the DOM hasn't created yet. Use `WebDriverWait` to make sure that the DOM be created before `sendKeys`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SEARCH"))

element.sendKeys(" ")
```